# ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Cancel() not working

Tags: xamarin, uwp, zxing

I'm developing a mobile application on Xamarin Forms for UWP, Android and IOS on Visual Studio.

I'm currently testing the app on my computer(Windows 10) and my phone (also Windows 10).

I'm using Zxing MobileBarcodeScanner to scan multiple barcodes.

When i press the back button i call the MobileBarcodeScanner.Cancel().

The only thing that it does is to close the camera. It doesn't depose the MobileBarcodeScanner's UI and i didn't found any solution for that.

Can anyone help me or suggest a solution?

Also the Cancel Button and the Flash Button aren't shown to the scanner UI.

Code:

```
private void showScanner()
{
    var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(App.coreDispatcher)
    {
        UseCustomOverlay = false,
        TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan",
        BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan",
        CancelButtonText = "Done",
        FlashButtonText = "Flash"
    }

    var opt = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000 };

    scanner.ScanContinuously(opt, HandleScanResult);
}

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    scanner.Cancel();
}

private void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    string msg;
    if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text)) // Success
    {
        msg = result.Text;
    }
    else // Canceled
    {
        msg = "Scanning Canceled!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing that it does is to close the camera. It doesn't depose the MobileBarcodeScanner's UI and i didn't found any solution for that

There is an issue in your code snippets. In the showScanner() method, you have defined a `scanner` variable, but in OnBackButtonPressed() method, looks like you have used a global variable also called `scanner`.

Maybe the following way should be correct:

```
MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;

private void showScanner(){
    scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(App.coreDispatcher) //Here, remove var
    {
        ......
    }

}
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    scanner.Cancel();
}
```

And if you have check the [Xamarin.Forms sample](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/0ec0cf47ccecf63ea9cb2721289397f080233333/Samples/Forms)

It uses the `ZXingScannerPage` to host your layout and handle some logics, including Cancel and ToggleTorch etc, see [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/0ec0cf47ccecf63ea9cb2721289397f080233333/Samples/Forms/Core/HomePage.cs#L13)

> Also the Cancel Button and the Flash Button aren't shown to the scanner UI.

Please use Custom Overlay, just set MobileBarcodeScanner.UseCustomOverlay property to true and check the sample code in [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/WindowsUniversal/Sample.WindowsUniversal/MainPage.xaml.cs#L77)

And also [ZXing.Net.Mobile Getting Started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile)

Comment: I am using the MobileBarcodeScanner to scan more than one barcodes at the same time. ZXingScannerPage it only supports a single scan each time. Also there isn't any way to make a ZXingScannerPage to handle a MobileBarcodeScanner. As i saw here https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/366/ this is a common problem with UWP

Comment: Also my code is based on this example https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49643/help-zxing-mobile-scancontinuously