# When Cancel button in "MobileBarCodeScanner()" is clicked, Application Exits and Crashes!(Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am looking for a solution when the cancel button in the "MobileBarcodeScanner" page is clicked, the app exists and crashes. I want to handle this issue, just to go back to the other view controllers when the "cancel" button is clicked

```
private async void CustomizedQrCodeScanner()
    {
        var scanner = MobileBarcodeScanner();
        var result = await scanner.Scan();
            if (result.Text != null)
            {
                qrcodeFromLiveCamera = result.Text;
                Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
                ShowMessage("QrCode Detected: ", result.Text);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What exception do you get when the app crashes!

Comment: I am not getting any exception, the app simply exits. Is there any way of accessing the "Cancel Button" in the Scanning page and when clicked, to assign it an exit from its page and load another view Controller ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38565054/8187800 , use Custom Overlay, just set MobileBarcodeScanner.UseCustomOverlay property to true

Comment: thanks man for your help.

I already saw this link, it keeps telling me that "OnBackButtonPressed" can not find any suitable method to override with this name. That's why i asked this question here.

Comment: i suggest to read this article [Avoid async void methods](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's because you have a Null Reference Exception.
You are checking for `result.Text` to be null. But when the user presses Cancel, `result` equals null and so it can't reach the Text property.
So just place a null check for `result` before your null check for `result.Text` and your problem should be fixed.

A simple way of doing that is using "[Safe-navigation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/)" as shownn

```
var result = await scanner.Scan();
if (result?.Text != null)
{
    qrcodeFromLiveCamera = result.Text;
    Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
    ShowMessage("QrCode Detected: ", result.Text);
}
```

A lot of good suggestions were also made above, but the best one was to create an "Exception Catchpoint". That would have told you that the type and line of your exception.

Comment: you are my saviour :), thanks a lot. I was reading a lot of materials and none of them helped me so far. 

But now, with your "result" checking condition. It is working properly.

Comment: Not a saviour! I actually faced the same problem for uploading a picture lol, so just trying to help others. Mark this as answered so others who face the same issue can find it readily

Comment: @Assegd ^ don't know if you received a notification from my comment since i didnt tag you

Comment: Hi Saamer,
yes you are right, i didn't get any notifiation but i dont know why. anyways i already have marked it as an answer

Comment: @Assegd accepted answers have a check mark, as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275362/11104068