# Autofac resolve the same class instance with different parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` application where I am using Autofac for DI.

SO what I want is quite simple but I am unable to do something which seems like a sinch to do.

So I have a class that has two constructors both of them have a single parameter and based on certain conditions I want to resolve either one. As an example, I have a class A and what I want is based on conditions B or C should be resolved.

Eg:

```
public class A
{

   public A(B bObject)
   {...}

   public A(C cObject)
   {...}
}
```

But I am unable to understand how to do this. I tried doing something like below:

Registration:

```
 builder.RegisterType<A>().
            UsingConstructor(typeof(C)).
            Named<A>(nameof(C));

 builder.RegisterType<A>().
            UsingConstructor(typeof(B)).
            Named<A>(nameof(B));
```

Resolving:

```
DiContainer.ResolveNamed<A>(nameof(B));
DiContainer.ResolveNamed<A>(nameof(C));
```

Note: 
I have already Registered B and C in the container as shown below:

```
builder.RegisterType<B>();
builder.RegisterType<C>()
```

I am a little new to AutoFac and I am not even sure if this is the correct way, I think it has something to do with me registering it twice I am not sure.

Any suggestion or help is strongly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a demo about using Autofac DI/IoC Container in Xamarin.Forms which  maybe can help you .https://github.com/rizamarhaban/XamarinAutofac .

Comment: I do not find a similar example there though, my basics are clear with regards to AutoFac its this specific thing that is annoying me here.

Comment: @FreakyAli 
Did you try using an Interface and register it with different instances?
Also maybe [this](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/896) helps you.

Comment: @MihaiBC When you say interface, do you want me to register it with two different interfaces and actually return the same page? Or am i misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @FreakyAli I meant that you should try to implement an Interface and try to register it with two different instances of the same implementation ( named B and C, each one with its specific constructor ) instead of registering the class directly.

Comment: At the end of the day that changes nothing don't you think?

Comment: @FreakyAli What is the condition that determines which constructor to use?

Comment: @FreakyAli also, this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and may be a signal of a deeper underlying design issue. The need for named injection is usually caused by ambiguity in your design and you should try to fix this root cause.

Comment: @Nkosi Well, I have an MVVM structure that uses the same View for 2 ViewModels, Based on the condition I have to decide which ViewModel to use. Condition is which page is being loaded.

Comment: @FreakyAli can you [edit] the post so that it is a true representation of what you are **actually** trying to do. Your previous comment shows that there is a lot of important details omitted from the problem that would greatly help those trying to help you solve the problem.

Comment: @FreakyAli you can use a lambda registration for that and pass parameter representing a condition at resolution time. Can you share the example of your condition?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski So basically I have a View(XAML)  and a couple of ViewModels, based on a boolean I have to load the View which is being registered in AutoFac and the ViewModel needs to come from the constructor as it goes to the base class through constructor injection. The problem is that I can have both pages in a single lifecycle and i feel your below code only registers one scenario and not the other.

Comment: Why not simplify the implementation by separating the class into two? The current way you are implementing it is harder to unit test and to maintain. I would recommend setting up the implementation in other ways that will the implementation simpler and you won't need the resolving by parameter name anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use an Autofac [lambda registration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#lambda-expression-components) for that and perform a registration using the following snippet (`c` parameter here is `IComponentContext` instance)

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(
    (c, p) =>
    {
        var condition = p.Named<bool>("condition");
        return condition ? new A(c.Resolve<B>()) : new A(c.Resolve<C>());
    });
builder.RegisterType<B>();
builder.RegisterType<C>();
```

Then resolve `A` by [passing](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html#parameters-with-lambda-expression-components) a parameter to lambda expression. You can use `TypedParameter` instead of named (constant values only) or `ResolvedParameter` (dynamic values)

```cs
var a = container.Resolve<A>(new NamedParameter("condition", true));
```

If you don't want to explicitly call `Resolve`, you can have a look at delegate [factories](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html#passing-parameters-without-explicitly-calling-resolve) (`Func<T>` for example)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround:

You can Wrap class B and C into another class which is then registered in autofac:

```
public class Wrapper {
  public B BObject;
  public C CObject;
}
```

You then can just do it a little bit like this (i dont know the correct way to resolve it as i dont have an IDE currently, but i hope you understand what iam doing here):

```
DiContainer.ResolveNamed<A>(new Wrapper(){BObject = Binstance});
```

Another solution:

What you can also do is registering B or C depending on what you want.

If you want that the class will be instantiated with B, register B on autofac, then resolve the class.

But the class needs to have two constructors. One with B as parameter and one with C ...

i think Autofac will resolve then depending on what got registered.

Comment: The thing is I will be needing both, it's not like I need one for the current execution and another for another. the same set of executions can have both the usages. It is basically a generic UI page with different ViewModels based on the correct scenario

Comment: Then you should use a Wrapper like i described. But i honestly think you are doing something wrong. Why not split these things up with a little bit of inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were very close, you literally needed to pass a [`Parameter`](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html#available-parameter-types) definition to your `Resolve`

```
public class B { }
public class C { }
public class A
{
    public A(B bObject){ Console.WriteLine("I am constructor A typeof(B)");}
    public A(C cObject){ Console.WriteLine("I am constructor A typeof(C)");}    
}

void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<A>().UsingConstructor(typeof(B)).Named<A>(nameof(B));
    builder.RegisterType<A>().UsingConstructor(typeof(C)).Named<A>(nameof(C));

    //it doesn't really matter if these are registered as you're using nameof() to identify the objects - that's essentially string
    builder.RegisterType<B>();
    builder.RegisterType<C>();

    var container = builder.Build();

    var a1 = container.ResolveNamed<A>(nameof(B), new TypedParameter(typeof(B), new B()));
    var a2 = container.ResolveNamed<A>(nameof(C), new TypedParameter(typeof(C), new C()));  
}
```